# isPrototypeOf() function on primitive

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

[Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) states that

> The isPrototypeOf() method checks if an object exists in another object's prototype chain.

When I create a primitive variable, say

`var a = 0;`

And check for its [[Prototype]] (not `a.prototype`),

`console.log(a.__proto__); //on chrome`

It prints `Number {0, isDivisibleBy2: ƒ, constructor: ƒ, toExponential: ƒ, toFixed: ƒ, …}`. Apparently, this value seems to be what's inside the `Number.prototype`.

So, I expect `Number.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a);` to return true, since `Number.prototype` does indeed exist within the prototype chain of `a` (the __proto __ chain).

But instead, theboutput for `Number.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a);` is false.

```js
var a = 0;
console.log(a.__proto__);

console.log(Number.prototype);

console.log(Number.prototype === a.__proto__);
console.log(Number.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a));
```

I think I might be misunderstanding something... I believe that `value.__proto__` is the right way to access the prototype chain (understang from [this mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#:%7E:text=Each%20object%20has%20a%20private,with%20null%20as%20its%20prototype.&text=Nearly%20all%20objects%20in%20JavaScript,top%20of%20a%20prototype%20chain.)). Is it just that `isPrototypeOf()` does not work on primitive?

Can someone help me clear up and understand this weird phenomenon?

Comment: Try with `a = new Number(0)`. `number` and `Number` aren't the same. I suspect that's the problem. Probably doesn't work w/ primitives, like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is actually creating a new Number object from the primitive when you access a property on it or call a method, after which the new object is promptly thrown away. That is why you can access the `__proto__` property. The primitive, however, is not a Number object.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. I didn't know about the 'wrapper' concept, thank you for your help!

Comment: @KentaNomoto No problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the spec [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.isprototypeof), the first rule of `isProtoTypeOf` is "If Type(V) is not Object, return false" (Where V is the value passed to the method).

Comment: Oh, I never checked this site, but that makes a lot more sense now, it actually does sound more efficient to immidiately return `false` when receiving primitive LHS. Thank you for your help!